# How to access all the slots on a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   
    Object[][] rubric = new Object[3][3];
    //[blue]    [red]   [green]
    //[white]   [yellow][orange]
    //[green]   [blue]  [white]

    rubric[0][0]="Blue";
    rubric[0][1]="Red";
    rubric[0][2]="Green";
    rubric[1][0]="White";
    rubric[1][1]="Yellow";
    rubric[1][2]="Orange";
    rubric[2][0]="Green";
    rubric[2][1]="Blue";
    rubric[2][2]="White";

    for(int i = 0; i < rubric.length; i++){
        if()
    }
```

I wanted to set up a condition saying if "all the slots are white, the rubric is solved", else "rubric not solved." What would be the syntax in the if statement to access all the slots in the array to set up the conditions?

Comment: Think about the fact that `rubric[i]` is itself an array and that you can have a loop inside another loop (using a different index like `j` to traverse it).

Comment: As an aside, `rubric` is clearly an array of `String` arrays, so it should be declared as `String[][]`, not as `Object[][]` unless you have a **very** good reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none. You have to iterate over every element (given your data structure)

```
boolean isSolvedWall(Object[][] rubic,String expectedColor){
   for(int i=0;i<rubric.length;i++){
     for(int j=0;j=rubic[i].length;j++){
       if(!expectedColor.equals(rubic[i][j])) return false;
     }
   }
}
return true;
```

and use it as

```
isSolvedWall(rubic,"white");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Object[][] rubric = new Object[3][3];
        //[blue]    [red]   [green]
        //[white]   [yellow][orange]
        //[green]   [blue]  [white]

        rubric[0][0]="Blue";
        rubric[0][1]="Red";
        rubric[0][2]="Green";
        rubric[1][0]="White";
        rubric[1][1]="Yellow";
        rubric[1][2]="Orange";
        rubric[2][0]="Green";
        rubric[2][1]="Blue";
        rubric[2][2]="White";
        
        boolean allWhite=true;
        for(int i = 0; i < rubric.length; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < rubric[i].length; j++){
               
               if(rubric[i][j] != "White") {
                   allWhite=false;
               }
               }
           }
        System.out.println(allWhite);
        }
```

Comment: you can break out after setting allWhite to false..